# Redux form field autocapitalize attribute

Tags: ios, reactjs, redux-form

I'm trying to pass the non-standard [autocapitalize](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-autocapitalize) attribute to a [redux-form Field](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/Field.md/):

```
<Field
  name="theName"
  autocapitalize="none"
  component={Input}
  label="Name"
  placeholder="name"
/>
```

But I can't see the attribute in the generated HTML.
Is there a way to pass extra attributes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React props use the camelCase syntax.. so `autocapitalize` needs to be `autoCapitalize`.

[Here's a list of all supported HTML props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes).

> accept acceptCharset accessKey action allowFullScreen allowTransparency alt async autoComplete autoFocus autoPlay capture cellPadding cellSpacing challenge
>   charSet checked cite classID className colSpan cols content contentEditable
>   contextMenu controls coords crossOrigin data dateTime default defer dir
>   disabled download draggable encType form formAction formEncType formMethod
>   formNoValidate formTarget frameBorder headers height hidden high href hrefLang
>   htmlFor httpEquiv icon id inputMode integrity is keyParams keyType kind label
>   lang list loop low manifest marginHeight marginWidth max maxLength media
>   mediaGroup method min minLength multiple muted name noValidate nonce open
>   optimum pattern placeholder poster preload profile radioGroup readOnly rel
>   required reversed role rowSpan rows sandbox scope scoped scrolling seamless
>   selected shape size sizes span spellCheck src srcDoc srcLang srcSet start step
>   style summary tabIndex target title type useMap value width wmode wrap

Comment: With a FormControl, I didn't see any error. But adding a simple input provided the error below. `<input type="text" autocapitalize="none" />` Changing from autocapitalize to autoCapitalize in the FormControl resolved the issue. Including the error message here for search engines.

`error  Unknown property 'autocapitalize' found, use 'autoCapitalize' instead  react/no-unknown-property`